# How to typehint method to return generic type object in typescript?

Tags: generics, typescript, interface

I want to in an interface that a method should return the generic type . Yet when I write:

```
export interface  Call<T> {
    invoke(): <T>
}
```

I get the error: `( Expected`.

I had before typehinted methods to return a `Promise<T>` and it worked:

```
export interface  Call<T> {
    invoke(): Promise<T> // no error here, yet I do not want to return a promise of <T>
}
```

I then tried to:

```
export interface  Call<T> {
    invoke(): Object<T>
}
```

yet this leads to: `Type Object is not generic`.

How to typehint method in an interface to return generic object of type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use like this.

```
export interface  Call<T> {
    invoke(): T
}
```

Comment: Easy typos are the hardest typos T_T